# Web application as native for mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am creating a web application using jQuery Mobile and I want to convert it to a native-like application.

I know that there is some tools like PhoneGap that can create native application from html and js files. but my app can't be on user's phone. **It has some server-side process and the result is generated by server.** I mean, users also can open application with their web browser (on phone, tablet, PC, etc.)

Is there any way to convert my app to a native app using PhoneGap? Or using other tool?

Another problem is, there is lots of javascript files, which should be loaded from client for better speed. (downloading lots of javascript files **each time user opens the app** is not a good idea!)

What is your idea here? How can I load javascripts locally while application is server side? Some caching arguments? or ...? How?

Comment: Also, you if you have a lot of javascript files, concat them and gzip them into one big file.

Comment: @Jlange OK, but how to cache that big file locally using PhoneGap or other similar software?

Comment: PhoneGap doesn't really require a cache, it converts your jQuery application to native code. I was referencing your webapp specifically, sorry kind of off topic.

Comment: Sorry, my application has a server-side with ASP.NET MVC, and pages are creating remotely. I just want PhoneGap to cache `js` and `css` files, instead of downloading them every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're looking for.
Why can't your app be on the user's phone? You can create a web service that is hosted on your server, and the phone app can talk to that.
You can use [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) to easily convert your html/js/css files to native phone apk/application files(not sure what they're called on iOS).

**Edit:**
Ah. So they can currently view it in a browser, but you want to have them be able to download it as an app as well? I suppose you could use PhoneGap to create an app that they download on their phone, but all it does is contain a WebView that points to the online version of your application.
Or, you could create a bookmark icon that opens your site instead of having to create an actual application.

Comment: I have almost completed programming, and It is completely web-based. I mean, you can browse it with web browser and it loads completely. But Also It should be available for mobile applications (maybe with PhoneGap). But javascript files should be stored locally by caching or other method. How to do this?

Comment: PhoneGap will be all be stored locally. You are basically converting it from a webapp to a native application. Meaning it will no longer run in the browser either.

Comment: I didn't get what you said about WebView and PhoneGap. Also it should use local javascripts (on user's phone) instead of downloading remote javascripts. (Some injecting local js files should be good)

Comment: If you want anything to be on their phone you'll either have to create an app (either natively or with PhoneGap), or cache the js files from your website. If you went with creating the app you'd have to make a webservice to handle data transfer. If you went with caching they'd have to download the js files at least once.

Comment: And will App Store (Apple and Android) Accept this type of application?

Comment: If you use PhoneGap / PhoneGap Build and convert it yes.

Comment: And how to load website from PhoneGap and cache js files??